# Custom Info Window for Google Maps in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am new to Swift and coding altogether.

So far I've got the Custom info window to show. However, I've been having issues in populating the data into it. I think I am missing something here, however, I can't really understand what is wrong with it.

I've used break points to check if the data is correctly populating and it is, however, it does not update on the map. I get the dummy text that I have entered.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class LocationsViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    var branch: Branch?

    var tappedMarker : GMSMarker?
    var customInfoWindow : CustomInfoWindow?

    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 25.1972948, longitude: 55.3266862, zoom: 10.0))

    var mapViewContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let getDirectionsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Get Directions", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    func getDirections() {

        if userLocation != nil {

            guard let userLocationLatitude = userLocation?.coordinate.latitude else { return }
            guard let userLocationLongitude = userLocation?.coordinate.longitude else { return }

            let directionsUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=\(userLocationLatitude),\(userLocationLongitude)&destination=25.1855878,55.2407415"
            let encodedUrl = directionsUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
            guard let url = URL(string: encodedUrl!) else { return }

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Get Directions using:", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options:[:], completionHandler: { (_) in })
            }))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maps", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        mapViewContainer = mapView

        self.mapView.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(mapViewContainer)
        mapViewContainer.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        view.addSubview(getDirectionsButton)
        getDirectionsButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 50, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)


        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        //25.1855878,55.2407415
        let alsafaMarker = GMSMarker()
        alsafaMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 25.1855878, longitude: 55.2407415)
        alsafaMarker.title = "Al Safa Park Branch"
        alsafaMarker.snippet = "112 Al Hadiqa Rd \nT: 043218838 \nSun to Sat | 11:00am - 2:00am"
        alsafaMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker")
        alsafaMarker.appearAnimation = .pop
        alsafaMarker.map = mapView

        //25.2347973,55.4743648
        let lastExitMarker = GMSMarker()
        lastExitMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 25.2347973, longitude: 55.4743648)
        lastExitMarker.title = "Last Exit Branch"
        lastExitMarker.snippet = "Last Exit Al Khawaneej - D89\n T: 0544422138 \nOpen 24 Hours"
        lastExitMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker")
        lastExitMarker.appearAnimation = .pop
        lastExitMarker.map = mapView


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mooyahLabelLogo"))

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.tappedMarker = GMSMarker()
        self.customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindow().loadView()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        userLocation = location

    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        print("marker was tapped")
        tappedMarker = marker

        if let tappedMarkerTitle = tappedMarker?.title {

            if let tappedMarkerSnippet = tappedMarker?.snippet {

                branch = Branch(name: tappedMarkerTitle, snippet: tappedMarkerSnippet)
            }
        }


        // get location of the tapped marker
        let position = marker.position
        mapView.animate(toLocation: position)
        let point = mapView.projection.point(for: position)
        let newPoint = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
        let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newPoint)
        mapView.animate(with: camera)

        let opaqueWhite = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
        customInfoWindow?.layer.backgroundColor = opaqueWhite.cgColor
        customInfoWindow?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        customInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: position)
        self.mapView.addSubview(customInfoWindow!)

        return false
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        let view = CustomInfoWindow()

        view.branchNameLabel.text = branch?.name
        view.branchSnippetLabel.text = branch?.snippet

        return view
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        customInfoWindow?.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        let position = tappedMarker?.position
        customInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: position!)
        customInfoWindow?.center.y -= 130
    }


}


import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class CustomInfoWindow: UIView {

    let branchNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Branch Name"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()

    let branchSnippetLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "This is where the full address will be. This is a very long address \nT: 043218838 \nSun to Sat | 11:00am - 2:00am"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 4
        label.textColor = UIColor.gray
        return label
    }()


    let getDirectionsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Get Directions", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    func handleDirections() {
        print("Get Directions button tapped")
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func loadView() -> CustomInfoWindow{
        let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindow

        customInfoWindow.addSubview(branchNameLabel)
        branchNameLabel.anchor(top: customInfoWindow.topAnchor, left: customInfoWindow.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 15, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        customInfoWindow.addSubview(branchSnippetLabel)
        branchSnippetLabel.anchor(top: branchNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: branchNameLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: customInfoWindow.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 15, width: 0, height: 0)

        customInfoWindow.addSubview(getDirectionsButton)
        getDirectionsButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: customInfoWindow.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 15, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        getDirectionsButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customInfoWindow.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        return customInfoWindow
    }

}


import UIKit

class Branch {
    var name: String?
    var snippet: String?

    init(name: String, snippet: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.snippet = snippet
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true`?

Comment: That has no effect on the code